# SQL Querying: Getting the top five tuples based on a value where the value could be the same for some tuples

Tags: mysql, sql

As explained in the title, I am trying to get the top five tuples from a table based on a value that could be the same across some of the tuples. Also, if the fifth tuple's value is the same as other tuples' values in the same table, I need to display them as well. As an example, suppose I have the table with the following values:

- Person A: Value 12
- Person B: Value 12
- Person C: Value 12
- Person D: Value 15
- Person E: Value 16
- Person F: Value 17
- Person G: Value 20

I need to display this:

- Person G: Value 20
- Person F: Value 17
- Person E: Value 16
- Person D: Value 15
- Person C: Value 12
- Person B: Value 12
- Person A: Value 12

As one can see, despite Persons C-G having the "top five" values, the table also includes Persons A and B because they have the same value as Person C. Also, one can see that executing a query such as

```
Select * from Person order by Value desc limit 5
```

would not produce this table as it would exclude Persons A and B. Can anyone provide me with some help regarding this matter? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean MySQL and not SQL Server (please edit your tags).  If so, you can use a subquery with `in` to get the ties:

```
Select *
From person
Where value In (
    Select value
    From person
    Order By value Desc
    Limit 5)
Order by value Desc
```

Depending on your desired results, you may need to use `distinct` in your subquery.  A little unclear with your sample data.

---

Alternatively, you could use a `join`:

```
Select p.*
From person p
   join (
    Select distinct value
    From person
    Order By value Desc
    Limit 5) p2 on p.value = p2.value
Order by p.value Desc
```

(I used `distinct` with this example to show the difference.)